# Manipulate Google results page to add a section on the RHS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a `Chrome Extension`, where in, based on the search query I want to display some stuff(let's assume `links` for now) on the *RHS* of the Google results page. Very similar to what [Wajam](http://www.wajam.com/) does.

I understand I need to use [Content-Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) for such tasks, which is clear and fine.

The problem is, Google seems to return `divs` with different IDs each time based on the query in its `html`. For instance if you search for a movie name, there seems to be different set of IDs in the html as opposed to, let's say when you search for a `Javascript` error message.

I wonder how [Wajam](http://www.wajam.com/) has implemented its plugin, which works so reliably and displays links on the RHS.

[image]

How should I go about it? Any specific IDs you can see in the html that I can use or build upon reliably?

Just to be clear for folks who are not into `Chrome Extensions`, the question **doesn't** require knowledge of Extension architecture/APIs. It's a seemingly simple `html/javascript/css` related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Chrome Extensions developement, but I tried to understand Google results page structure, and I hope that will help you :

Every google result page has a `#rhs` div, even if there are no additional informations on the right. This div has an unique id, so I think it would be easy to put dynamical content inside.

I've tried with Web Developer Tools, and that worked very well : 
[image: sreenshot]

I think you'll just have to append content to this div to get what you want : the "different IDs based on the query" may be children of this parent and unique `#rhs` div. So I don't think you have to care about these children "random id" divs, just append your content (custom css, images, videos...) in this `#rhs` div :)

if you want to try with a Web Developer Tool :
just paste this code instead of the original `<div id="rhs">...</div>`

```
<div id="rhs" style="
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 16px;">

    Put whatever you want here

    <div style="
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        background-color: #eee;
        margin: 20px;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
        box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
        font-size: 1.4em;
    ">

        Custom CSS

    </div>

    <img src="http://myrrix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/stackoverflow.png"> images
    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="340" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=0&amp;origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

and you'll get the same result as me.

Hope I helped you ! :)